# call a function from another file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Inside the below `job.js` node script how can i call `/getJobs` .Am using following way but getting `$ is not defined.`

```
job.js

var jobScedule = function (time, jobid) {
var params = {
            "id": jobid
        };
          $.get('/getJobs', params, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
}
```

script.js

```
.......
......
 switch(context.pathname) {
        case '/getJobs':
          testUtils.runTest(context);
          break; 
}
```

Comment: `$.get()` looks like a jQuery method. Have you included jQuery?

Comment: Not inclued jquey.it is a node script.i tried this way.coz i dont know how to call that/getjobs in node.js

Answer (score 1):

You need [request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request). It will help you to make http requests:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
  }
})
```

Comment: is it suitable for /getjobs also?

Comment: @Sush What *is* `/getjobs`?

Comment: in jquey am using `$.get('/getJobs', params, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }); like this.but i want to call this from node.js`

Comment: What you are doing is just a simple ajax (GET request). What I'm suggesting is a nodejs module which does the same thing.